# PHP ElseIf Statement with Numbers

Tags: php, if-statement

The user can only enter a number between 1 and 5 - if they enter 0, leave the field blank or enter a number greater than 5 it will be default reset to 5. 1,2,3,4 are accepted otherwise.

```
$max=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["max"]);

if ($max=="0" || $max==""){
    $max_r="5";
} elseif ($max > "5"){
    $max_r="5";
} else {
    $max_r=$max;
}
```

However it always spits out 5.

Comment: Why not? I use it for GET and POST - can't be to careful; I thought if someone makes a form on external server..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're comparing strings and not integers. Try `$max = (int) $_POST['max']` and don't wrap the values in quotes. Then, you can always escape `$max` before writing it to the DB.

```
$max = (int) $_POST['max'];

if ( ! $max || $max > 5){
  $max_r = 5;
} else {
  $max_r = $max;
}
```

Or, you could go one-liner FTW:

```
$max_r = ( ! $max || $max > 5) ? 5 : $max;
```

Comment: I got a fever, and the only thing that's gonna cure it is **more ternary operation**!

Comment: Code does not work. If I enter a number greater than 5 it prints 5. If less it prints 5

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid What do you want it to print out? I just duplicated the functionality you expressed in your code?

Comment: If the user enters 0 it must print out 5, if they enter greater than 5 it must print out 5 - any number otherwise would print that number so all output would be 5 accept 1,2,3,4 - said that above. sorry if i was not clear

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid The above code does exactly that. And I tested just to make sure I wasn't crazy. It does allow negative numbers, though, so you'll have to make that change if needed.

Comment: `$max = (int) $_POST["max"];
$max_r = ( ! $max || $max > 5) ? 5 : $max;`
It does not insert 1-4

Comment: I can't speak to your code to insert into the DB, but If you try `var_dump($max_r)` you'll see the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = intval($_POST['max']);
if($max < 0 || $max > 5){
   $max = 5;
}
```